# Default Status of "Unknown" in Open

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I often see people using the `OPEN` statement without explicitly specifying a `STATUS`. In the Fortran 90 and 2008 standards, this is said regarding `STATUS`:

> If UNKNOWN is specified, the status is processor dependent. If this specifier is omitted, the default value is UNKNOWN.

I interpret this to mean, if `STATUS` is omitted, anything can happen, depending what machine you're using.

Yet, from doing some tests, it seems the default behavior (when `STATUS` is omitted), is `REPLACE`. But I cannot find this behavior documented in the gfortran compiler manual (from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

Question: Is this `REPLACE` indeed the default behavior in popular compilers like gfortran and ifort? If so, is this actually documented (but I just happened to not find it)?

Comment: Undocumented behavior rarely means random.

Comment: The recommended specifiers in `OPEN` statements are `file`, `access`, `status`, and `action`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In common compilers the `UNKNOWN` behaves quite similarly in all of them. But it definitely is not equivalent to `REPLACE`! That choice would overwrite your data you want to read!

The IBM XL Fortran manual specifies this:

> UNKNOWN, to connect an existing file, or to create and connect a new
>   file. If the file exists, it is connected as OLD. If the file does not
>   exist, it is connected as NEW.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was `REPLACE` because I was only using the opened files for output.

Comment: elaborating a bit. `open(..status = 'replace')` clears an existing file immediately on the `open` statement regardless of whether you write to it.  `old` or `unknown` overwrites an existing file only on the first `write`.  I'm puzzled now what other behavior could there be for `unknown` and why not standardize the near-universal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

UNKNOWN means create the file if not yet existing, then open it.

Comment: From where do you get this information as in the standard it is still stated: If UNKNOWN is specified, the status is processor dependent. If this specifier is omitted, the default value is
UNKNOWN.