# Fortran90 - compiled program creates a blank csv file instead of reading the existing one

Tags: csv, gcc, fortran, fortran90

In short: I am trying to load a csv file but the program always overwrites the existing file as an empty new file.

Longer: I am pretty new to Fortran, so bear with me. I am trying to read data from a csv file into a fortran program. Now I didn't write the program and it is pretty big, so I can't post the whole thing here. The program consists of a whole bunch of .f90 files and everything is compiled using a makefile. Now since I am loading the gcc module before compiling, I am assuming that it is compiled using GNU Fortran, because it is part of gcc. (idk how to find out if that is correct)

The compiler returns an executable in a different directory. When I execute the program in that directory it apparently overwrites the existing .csv file with a new blank one, so the program only reads "End of File". I don't know why it always creates a new file, how do I stop it from doing so?

As a side note, the csv file I am trying to read simply consists of a single column of floats, e.g.
"0.01, 0.13, 0.041,..." etc.
The code that I inserted into a subroutine of one of the .f90 files is the following:

```
real*8, dimension(nz) :: Nsq
integer :: i

open(10, file='Nsq.csv')

do i=1,20
     read(10, *) Nsq(i)
enddo

close(10)
```

I have also tried to write a small test program, essentially running the same code as above. That one works just fine and outputs the contents of the csv file without any issues. For that one I use gfortran to compile it.
I have no experience in Fortran at all, so I am completely stumped, why this happens. I know the chances are slim that you guys can help me with this, since I can't provide the whole source code. But maybe someone has an idea why this occurs. Maybe you know an alternate way of reading csv files?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to open the file with ```open(10, file='Nsq.csv', status='old', action='read')``` to see if it shows some error.

Comment: yes, together with kvantour's answer i figured it out. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open-statement in Fortran `OPEN(connect-spec-list)`, has a lot of connection specifications which define how an external file should be managed (see. [Fortran 2018 Standard sec 12.5.6](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)).

When you open a file using the simplest form of the open-statement:

```
OPEN(unit=unitid,file="filename")
```

A lot of default assumptions are made such as: `ACCESS="SEQUENTIAL", ASYNCHRONOUS="NO", BLANK="NULL", ...`. The most important ones, however, are `ACTION` and `STATUS` which define the purpose of the file. The action specification states if you want to use the file for reading, writing or both, while the `status` essentially defines if we work on an existing file or not, and what we should do with it (replace it, keep it, ...)

Both these specifications have a default compiler dependent state.

In the *Intel compiler suit*, the default is `action="readwrite", status="unknown"` (see [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/file-operation-i-o-statements/open-statement-specifiers/open-action-specifier.html#open-action-specifier) and [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/file-operation-i-o-statements/open-statement-specifiers/open-status-specifier.html#open-status-specifier))
Intel defines the `status="unknown"` as :*Indicates the file may or may not exist. If the file does not exist, a new file is created and its status changes to 'OLD'.*

The Gnu compiler suit has a different take on this. The default action is defined by a set of rules which depend on its accessibility if the file exists (`+rw,+r-w,-r+w`) (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Files-opened-without-an-explicit-ACTION_003d-specifier.html#Files-opened-without-an-explicit-ACTION_003d-specifier)). The behaviour for the default `action="unknown"` is not documented but seems to be `REWRITE` (see [Default Status of "Unknown" in Open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27340943/8344060))

It is advised to use a proper method if you know what you want to do with the file:

```
OPEN(newunit=unitid, file="filename", action="read", status="old")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very illuminating answer that actually solved my problem. I was starting to give up hope. Thank you for answering so quickly.